# jQuery Insert/Delete a grid

Tags: jquery

If the user clicks on "Add", I need to temporarily disable all the add/delete listeners until myid loses the focus.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function OnLoad() {
    var myCounter = 0;
    $('.insert').live('click', function() {
        var currentRow = $(this).parents("tr:first");
        var newRow = currentRow.clone(true);
        newRow.children('td:last').empty().append('<input name="myid">');
        currentRow.after(newRow);
        document.myForm.myid.focus();
    });
    $('.delete').live('click', function() {
        if(confirm("Are you sure?")){
            $(this).parents("tr").remove();
        }
    });
}
google.load("jquery", "1");
google.setOnLoadCallback(OnLoad);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="myForm">
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td class="insert">Add</td>
<td class="delete">Erase</td>
<td>Sample data goes here</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

In other words, I don't want them to click "Add" and then "Add" again.

Comment: You should change `append('<input name="myid">')` to `append('<input name="myid" />')` (A self-closing tag)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make a variable that tracks whether the user is allowed to click `Add`.

When Add is clicked, set the variable to `false`.

When the textbox loses focus, set it to `true` again, like this:

```
$('input[name=myid').live('focusout', function() { canAdd = true; }));
```

Then, add `if(!canAdd) return;` to the beginning of the `Add` handler

Comment: live('focusout'), function should be
live('focusout', function

Answer (score 2):

You might find it easier to set a variable when an input gets focus, and clear it when it looses it. The onClick functions for add and erase should check whether or not this chosen variable is set, and either return or continue depending on it.

Alternately, you can use buttons for add and remove, then set/clear the disabled attribute of the add/remove buttons when inputs receiving and loose focus.

Answer (score 1):

```
var adding = false;
$('.insert').live('click', function() {
    if(!adding){
        // Do stuff
        adding = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: that won't live outside the scope of the current executing input

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the code of each event handler into its own function:

```
function insertHandler() {
    var currentRow = $(this).parents("tr:first");
    var newRow = currentRow.clone(true);
    newRow.children('td:last').empty().append('<input name="myid">');
    currentRow.after(newRow);
    document.myForm.myid.focus();
}
```

At the beginning of your two method handlers, unbind the `click` event:

```
$('.insert').live('click', function() {
    $(this).unbind("click");
    insertHandler();
});
```

Add a new handler, binding to the `focusout` event using `live` (as your input is programatically inserted), which rebinds your function to your event:

```
$("input[name=myid]").live("focusout", function() {
    $(".insert").live("click", insertHandler);
});
```

Comment: I think I need to pass 'this' to insertHandler.

Comment: I got it to work (I am using Firefox) by passing currentRow to insertHandler.
Thanks for your help!
Stay tuned for my next question!

Comment: Oh wait!  For some reason, the "Add" is not unbinding.

Comment: Try using `$(this).die();` instead of `$(this).unbind("click");`